# Setting border in css

Tags: html, asp.net, css

My border moves when I set padding to the left in my `.sidebar` in CSS or a margin in `.sidebar  td`.

I want the padding here but I want the border to go all the way across but it moves with the text every time I add the padding/margin.

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 865px;
    height: inherit;
    border: groove;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: -265px;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.sidebartda {
    border: 1 px solid;
    display: table;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    border-color: #D6D6D6;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-top-style: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.sidebartda:link {
    color: #eeeeee;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="Develop.aspx#FreeAPI">Free API</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="Develop.aspx#ProAPI">Pro API</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="Develop.aspx#Platform">Platform</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My link color doesn't seem to work either except on 2 random links on one of the pages.
Any tips?

Comment: where it is in the question?

Comment: is this u want http://jsfiddle.net/wEcSd/1/

Comment: Thank but no. The 3 links are within 1 table but are seperated by a bottom border line and indented slightly. At the moment my bottom border starts at the indent but I want to ignore the indent and cover the whole cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEcSd/2/) for the same.

```
.sidebar td a:link{color:#000;}
.sidebar td a:visited{color:#000;}
.sidebar td a:active{color:#000;}
.sidebar td a:hover{color:#000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**a:link** only works on unvisited links (that is anchor tags with href attribute set that you have nto clicked on). So, if you ever visited a link, **a:link** css rule will not apply to it. For styling those, you have to set **a:visited**.

Check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_link.asp

Answer (score 0):

aren´t you missing the `dot at "sidebar" (line 1)?` - the link color is not working because the link color is only working on links you´ve never visited before. `a:visited, a:link, a:hover` might be a good option too.

padding and margin are better written: padding: 10px (top) 0px(right) 0px (bottom) 20px (left); -> `padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;` same with margin..